# How do I return value correctly from CloudKit completionHandler

Tags: ios, multithreading, asynchronous, cloudkit

My app. saves a record to iCloud with CloudKit. I would like to check for errors and set a flag based on success or failure. I return the flag via the function call but that does not work. The return value is false even when the save is a success and there is no error. It's because the `saveHistoryRecordToCloud` function returns false before the completion handler sets `savedToCloud` to true. I understand this has to do with the asynchronous network call but I'm **very** new to this and clearly don't understand how to handle it. How do I set what `saveHistoryRecordToCloud` returns accurately?  Thanks for the help! The code is below.

```
    func saveHistoryRecordToCloud(currentWalk: MyCustomTabBarController.Walk ) -> Bool
{
    var savedToCloud = false
    let history = CKRecord(recordType: "History")
    history.setValue(currentWalk.startTime, forKey: "startTime")
    history.setValue(currentWalk.duration, forKey: "duration")

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    publicDatabase.save(history) { (savedRecord, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print ("Error saving to iCloud " + error.debugDescription)
        } else
        {
            savedToCloud = true
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating
            }
            print ("Saving History worked!! recordID,recordName = ",savedRecord?.recordID.recordName ?? "" )
        }
    }
    return (savedToCloud)
}
```

and the call

```
        tbc!.currentWalk.savedToCloud = saveHistoryRecordToCloud(currentWalk: tbc!.currentWalk)
    print ("tbc!.currentWalk.savedToCloud ", tbc!.currentWalk.savedToCloud)  // always returns false
```

Comment: Good points: You understood it's async. You just need to add a closure too to `saveHistoryRecordToCloud`, where you "return" a bool "success" and call the closure in the `save(history)()` one.

Comment: @Larme How would I do that, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct about the calling sequence. One approach is to implement "callback" (or "closure") functions. Assume your current code looks something like this (this is pseudo code, I probably wouldn't get the Swift syntax right):

```
function1()
{
     line1
     line2
     tbc!.currentWalk.savedToCloud = saveHistoryRecordToCloud(currentWalk: tbc!.currentWalk)
     print ("tbc!.currentWalk.savedToCloud ", tbc!.currentWalk.savedToCloud)  // always returns false
     line 5
     line 6
}
```

Using a callback function, you'd break that code into two functions like so:

```
function1()
{
     line1
     line2
     tbc!.currentWalk.savedToCloud = saveHistoryRecordToCloud(currentWalk: tbc!.currentWalk)
}
```

and

```
function1_callback(savedToCloud)
{
     print ("tbc!.currentWalk.savedToCloud ", savedToCloud)  
     line 5
     line 6
}
```

Call `function1_callback()` from the end of your completion handler, like so:

```
publicDatabase.save(history) { (savedRecord, error) in
    if error != nil
    {
        print ("Error saving to iCloud " + error.debugDescription)
    } else
    {
        savedToCloud = true
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating
        }
        print ("Saving History worked!! recordID,recordName = ",savedRecord?.recordID.recordName ?? "" )

        /* new callback added here */
        function1_callback(savedToCloud)
    }
}
```

The code flow starts with your first function, it calls the saving function, which begins the async saving process and then your code flow ends. When the async save completes, it fires the completion handler. The completion handler calls the callback function, passing in the results of the save operation, and your code flow resumes.

Comment: Thanks.  This works.  I also been playing with the closure as @Larme suggested.  Is there a recommended way?  The closure seems "cleaner" to me.

Comment: I suggest you go with whatever makes the most logical sense to you. Unless there are specific constraints (performance optimization, memory optimization, etc) it probably makes little difference in the end, other than the amount of time it takes you to re-learn how the code works when you have to modify it a year or two later. Besides, it's possible that the compiler may wind up treating both approaches in similar fashion. Please consider accepting the answer if it meets or your needs, or opening additional questions for followups.